# react-tooltip styling is off

Tags: reactjs, react-tooltip

For some reason my react-tooltip tooltips are not the same as everybody else's. I'm guessing some of my css is probably interfering with the tooltips but I can't figure out what it is.

this is what it looks like:

[image]

As you can see the 'arrow'  part of the tooltip is not smooth and has a weird rugged effect.

When I try my code in the demo sandbox it does not look like this

Any help as to what could be causing this is very welcome!

Comment: might be a zoom issue.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so the problem was that multiple "ReactTooltip" components were being loaded and were stacking on top of eachother... so make sure you only have one ReactTooltip being rendered!